# Transmiting data throught the Serial Port

Tags: compact-framework, serial-port

I'm working with the SerialPort class in the Compact Framework, but I can't recive more than 2047 bytes. Exists any limit for the amount of bytes that I can recive? or How can I setup the object? I was trying with the WriteBufferSize and ReadBufferSize properties but they didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that it is either a processor or platform limitation. [This post](http://forums.microsoft.com/MSDN/ShowPost.aspx?PostID=22421&SiteID=1) from the MSDN forums seems to confirm my suspicions.

Answer (score 0):

Can you set up a thread to pull the data into another (larger) buffer that you allocate yourself?  I'd say that's the best workaround.